# Too many connections error with redshift using sqlalchemy with pandas

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am using sqlalchemy in a flask application to create the engine to connect the redshift database.

I am having a loop and in each loop am executing the query and return a data frame with pandas.read_sql_query(query_string, engine).

When I run my program I am receiving below error with connecting redshift DB.

**psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  too many connections for user "user"**

Please advise how to handle the error in python and sqlalchemy in the flask app?

I have tried **poolclass=Nullpool** and using **engine.dispose()**
But none of them worked.

```
redshift_db = create_engine(db_url)
for id in list:
  data_frame = pd.read_sql_query(sql_strung,
                                 redshift_db,
                                 params={id': id})
```

Answer (score 0):

The database is not allowing multiple concurrent connections from the same API on the same table
You'd rather use a single query:

```
id_list_str = ', '.join([id for id in id_list])
sql_string = "select id, x, y, z from <db_table> where id in ANY(%s)".format(id_list)
data_frame = pd.read_sql_query(sql_strung, redshift_db)
```

For more you can read about this on the AWS documentation